# Authentication authorization ASP/NET MVC 3 using membership

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, authentication, asp.net-membership, authorization

I am looking for a good tutorial for securing an MVC 3 application the right way.
Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Membership is not a new thing for MVC It is same like in asp.net. I can recommend this old and good tutorial [Examining ASP.NET's Membership, Roles, and Profile](https://web.archive.org/web/20211020202857/http://www.4guysfromrolla.com/articles/120705-1.aspx) and this book [Professional ASP.NET 3.5 Security, Membership, and Role Management with C# and VB](http://www.wrox.com/WileyCDA/WroxTitle/Professional-ASP-NET-3-5-Security-Membership-and-Role-Management-with-C-and-VB.productCd-0470379308.html).